# Extending existing django applications

Tags: python, django, askbot

I am using an existing django app called askbot and which to extend some of it's features. Specifically I need to add new relationships into some of it's models.

This poses a problem for me as I would have to make alterations to it's model code, which I'd rather not do as this will break updatability etc.

Is there a better way to do this other than hacking other peoples code?

I've looked at options and considering either creating a app that applies patches to askbot's code or extending it's model, de-registering it and registering my own subclassed model, but I'm unsure of the best way to go about this.

Comment: Fork the project and make the alterations. Unless the project allows for models to be specified (in which case you could add in your own) nothing good will come of it otherwise.

Comment: So if I'm forking should I create separate apps for maintaining my own altered south migrations, dependencies etc to at least make upgrading slightly less painful?